# unnecessary register reset in FPGA

Tags: verilog, fpga, system-verilog

Assume I have some internal registers that I do not have to reset, for example, if I set them in the state before I use them - like buffer here, I do not give it any value on reset, and when the state transitions to STATE_1 (where I need the buffer) I load it:

```
always @(posedge clk or negedge reset_n) 
begin
   if(!reset_n) 
      state <= IDLE
   else begin
       case(state)
         IDLE: begin
             if(in1) begin
                buffer <= in2
                state <= STATE_1             
             end
         end
         STATE_1 :begin
             use buffer..
          end       
       endcase
   end
end
```

Is it really necessary to also include buffer in the async reset and to give it a value upon reset?
will the synthesis tool do it anyway? on what does this depend? what is good practice?
Because intuitively this feels more efficient because the synthesis will not have to find a way to wire the reset to the buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is safe not to reset a flip-flop. There are advantages to leaving out a reset:

- In an IC, that will result in a flip-flop without a reset being
  synthesised, which will be slightly smaller than one will a reset.
  That probably won't be the case in an FPGA, because a flip-flop with a reset  will
  be present anyway. (However, some FPGA synthesisers can make flip-flops
  out of LUTs and whether that is possible or not might depend on
  whether you have a reset or not.)
- In either an IC or an FPGA, routing resource will not be taken up
  routing the reset signal to your flip-flop.

However, in an IC, some design flows might mandate a reset for manufacturing-test purposes. That's not an issue in an FPGA.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on how you use the `buffer` signal. If it is only used in `STATE_1`, it is safe to not reset it. The EDA tool should not reset it except power on reset should set all registers to known state.